# User card displays links as HTML code

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, user-card

I took a look at [this question] but I don't think this is related.

In my full "About me", I use markup code to link to my linkedin and twitter account, and also added a summary block

```
<!-- summary: my summary text -->
```

Now for some strange reason, when expanded my user-card displays my summary text, and then the links from my full profile as html :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/xgouchet" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a> <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/xgouchet" rel="nofollow">LinkedIn</a> <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Xavier+Gouchet" rel="nofollow">Android applica...</a>
```

I don't know if this is just me (Firefox 14.0.1 / Windows XP) or if this is displayed like this to anyone but this is quite bothering. I don't mind having my links in there, but at least I don't want to have them as HTML code.

Also this also happen when I look at other users user-cards.

Comment: So you dont mind if they copy your link and put it in the browser, but you dont want them to be able to click it directly?

Comment: What does the `<!-- summary: my summary text -->` achieve, I'm not familiar with it?

Comment: @Rory: It's a custom summary to be displayed in the user card.

Comment: Yep - [I can reproduce the same bug](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L3V1S.png). Retag this [meta-tag:bug], please :)

Comment: @minitech you can retag it just as well as him :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Whoa! It's been so long... thanks.

Comment: @minitech hehe I blend easily.

Comment: @JoshMein I don't mind seeing m own links in my user card, but I dont want to see the whole HTML code as plain text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're reworking some old code in our views (typically making them *actually* views and not just string concatenations), and this encoding bug slipped through.

A fix for this is being deployed.

Note that because of some caching, it may take another hour or so for affected user cards to fix themselves.